# Virsh (libvirt-bin) is not able to communicate with Xen server

Tags: virtual-machine, xen, virsh, libvirt

I have installed the latest version of Xen server 6.5. Now I want to connect to it with `virsh` (libvirt-bin). When I do this I get the error

```
error:end of file while reading data: sh:nc:command not found: In-/out error
```

I find something on the internet that this could be because of an misconfigured user on the Xen server. Since today was my first time installing Xen ever, I am not comfortable with going into an shell and change some things and brake it. Maybe somebody could help me on where to start with looking at logs or maybe even the solution to the problem?

Question: What exactly does this error mean and how can I solve it?

Comment: make sure `libvirtd` daemon is running on server and `ssh` too

Comment: is `nc` (netcat) installed on both the local machine and the remote xen server?  that error message seems to indicate it's missing from one or both.

Comment: @arzyfex , I am able to SSH into the machine so SSH is running. How do I check if libvirtd is running. I am not familiar with the xen CLI, so maybe some hints would be great.

Comment: @cas , netcat was indeed not installed on the host (installed, did not make a difference). I looks like Xen looks a little like Centos (it responded to `yum install netcat` and `yum install nc`). Both are not available according to the response from the CLI. Am I doing it right or has the package a different name?